# Does my in-app purchase process make sense?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a free ios app which has an in-app purchase to upgrade to pro version to unlock some features. I don't have a server so I want to do it in a very simple way like below:

1. Purchase/restore:
   After purchase or restore successfully, I will write a value 'purchased' as true in local storage and unlock the pro features at the same time.
2. Launch app:
   Check value of 'purchased', if true, I'll unlock pro features; If not, lock pro features.

When user uninstall & reinstall my app, local storage will be missing, but they can click restore to go through procedure 1 to unlock the pro feature.

Does this in-app purchase process make sense? Do I miss some important parts?

Comment: you miss the part that it is easily crack-able by just changing one flag in the local storage on your phone to get the pro features without paying anything. If you are not worried about users doing that then your process is fine.

Comment: Can this "crack" happen on normal devices or only jailbreak devices?

Comment: I will just put it out  there that there a a couple of open source full solutions to the problem you are trying to solve. I'm not saying it might not be worth the exercise to build your own, but I put in a bunch of hours and quickly learned that a good solution would take forever to make.

I ended up using swifty storekit https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit but a google search can get you more choices.